# How to use completed_count to track task group completion in Celery?

Tags: task, celery, completion

I am trying to use "completed_count()" to track how many tasks are left in a group in Celery.

My "client" runs this:

```
from celery import group
from proj import do

wordList=[]
with open('word.txt') as wordData:
     for line in wordData:
         wordList.append(line)

readAll = group(do.s(i) for i in wordList)

result = readAll.apply_async()
while not result.ready():
     print(result.completed_count())
result.get()
```

The 'word.txt" is just a file with one word on each line.

Then I have the celery worker(s) set to run the do task as:

```
@app.task(task_acks_late = True)
def do(word):
    sleep(1)
    return f"I'm doing {word}"
```

My broker is pyamqp and I use rpc for the backend.

I thought it would print an increasing count of tasks for each loop on the client side but all I get are "0"s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in `completed_count` method. You are getting zeros because of result.ready() stays `False` after all the tasks have been completed. It seems like we have a bug with `rpc` backend, there is an issue on [github](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4084). Consider to change the backend setting to `amqp`, it is working correctly as I can see