# Celery Group tasks complete but completed_count is zero

Tags: celery

I'm using Celery 4.3.0 to create a group of tasks to run. When I do this the tasks themselves all execute successfully but the GroupResult completed count is always 0.

I'm using rabbitmq broker and have tried redis result backend and db result backend, it acts the same.

```
@shared_task(
    autoretry_for=(Exception,), retry_backoff=
    ignore_result=False, retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 3},
)
def some_task(*args, **kwargs):
    logger.info('some task')


def run_tasks():
   tasks = [some_task.s(), some_task.s()]
   result = group(*tasks).apply_async()
   while True:
       print(result.completed_count())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use completed\_count to track task group completion in Celery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859500/how-to-use-completed-count-to-track-task-group-completion-in-celery)

Answer (score 0):

You can update celery to 4.4.1. I had the same problem before updating.